# c++ stringstream concatenating string variables with integers and literal strings

Tags: c++, concatenation, stringstream

A bit new to c++ and attempting to concatenate variables of differing types and literal strings together to create a formatted output later, however I keep getting an error once I add in any literal strings with quotes such as "This in quotes" etc, below is my code of how I attempted to do it, any help will go a long way

```
 string format;

 std::stringstream stream;
 stream << "Work Ticket # "<< workTicket << " "<< clientNumber << "(" <<labDay << "/"<     labMonth << "/"<< labYear <<") : "<< labDesc;
 format = stream.str();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a typo in your code:

```
...labDay << "/"<     labMonth...
```

should read

```
...labDay << "/" << labMonth...
```

Whats's your exact error message?

Comment: Oh wow youre right it was a silly error on my part, dont know how I didnt spot that, thanks for your help!

Comment: will accept your answer in a few minutes when stackoverflow allows me to, thanks again